# Manipulating std::array in a function

Tags: c++, stdarray

I have a multidimensional array of fixed size in my code, and I need to be able to change the values within it in a separate function. I want to know, are std::arrays passed as references in a method or is a copy made? So can I do this:

```
using std::array;

void foo (array<array<int,WIDTH>,HEIGHT> bar);
//manipulates the values in the array
...

int main() {
  array<array<int,WIDTH>,HEIGHT> baz;
  ...
  foo(baz);
  //baz is changed
}
```

Or do I need to explicitly turn it into a reference? I fear that if I created an array function that returned a copy, it would be too messy and not as fast.

Comment: `std::array`is a regular class that behaves in regular ways. There are no types that get special treatment as parameters.

Comment: I assumed since it was a wrapper for c arrays that it would also be passed as a reference.

Comment: If you have an ordinary class definition that contained a C array, and then passed an instance of that class by value, the internal array member field would get **copied** into a new instance.  std::array does not behave differently.

Comment: I guess you're thinking of a C array's decaying into a pointer to its first element as a parameter. Note that in that case, the parameter does not have the same type as the array. The actual argument, which is a pointer, is copied like everything else.

Comment: So I was mistaken in how I thought C arrays worked, my apologies.

Comment: @Comrade_Comski *I assumed since it was a wrapper for c arrays* -- Doesn't matter what the class encapsulates.  It could be an array, or a blueprint layout of the Pentagon.  The rules of C++ applies to both.

Comment: Might be interesting: you can pass raw arrays as reference, too: `void foo(int(&array)[7]` would accept arrays of length 7. If you make a template of, you can pass arrays of arbitrary length. This is, for instance, how `std::begin` and `std::end` for arrays are implemented. Even the `sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)` pattern then still works, but you get number of elements easier via the template parameter...

Comment: @Comrade_Comski I imagine one of the design aims of `std::array` was to get away from the special treatment that regular arrays get. Otherwise what's the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass by reference (or pointer) if you want to avoid having a copy made:

```
void foo (array<array<int,WIDTH>,HEIGHT> &bar);
```

Answer (score 4):

> I want to know, are std::arrays passed as references in a method or is a copy made?

`std::array` is a value type. If you pass by value, a copy will (conceptually) be made.

This is different from the behaviour of a c-style array (`int bar[HEIGHT][WIDTH]`). c-style arrays are passed by reference. This is due to a fundamental design decision (some would say error) in the C language many moons ago.

> do I need to explicitly turn it into a reference?

If you wish to pass a reference, yes.

> I fear that if I created an array function that returned a copy, it would be too messy

Functional programmers would argue that it was cleaner.

> and not as fast.

Be careful of assumptions like this. For amongst other reasons,

a) Compilers don't always do as you tell them. They can write code that has the same effect as if they'd done what you tell them, but achieves the same result quicker. (google: "as-if rule c++")

b) Modern CPU architectures are specifically engineered to be extremely good at moving contiguous blocks of memory.

Write the cleanest code you can which, using abstract concepts to express your intent clearly. If the program runs too slowly, uses too much memory, uses too much power or your end users are complaining, then maybe is the time to concern yourself with by-reference or by-value optimisations.

However, I can assure you that any delays you are seeing in execution speed are much more likely to be in your treatment of IO or due to the selection of algorithms exhibiting high time complexity.

Comment: Thank you. Should I choose to return a copy, is the function guaranteed to delete the extra copy after it is finished?

Comment: @Daniel yes. Often the extra copy won't even be made. Compilers are pretty clever.

Comment: Pretty common as well: pass parameters by const reference, return a newly created result (`Matrix add(Matrix const& x, Matrix const& y);`)

Comment: @RichardHodges I am a bit in trouble with "C-style arrays being passed by reference" - as for my underständing, if it was so, 1. there shoudn't be a change of type (array decaying to pointer), 2. `sizeof` should yield size of array, not size of pointer. Even worse: one can *really* pass arrays by reference: `void f(int (&x)[7])` (apart from that detail, fine answer...)

Comment: @Aconcagua 1. yes, this is exactly what happens in reality. 2. welcome to the mess that is c-style arrays passed to functions. and yes, your example of `f` means exactly the same as if you had written `void f(int x[7])`

Comment: @RichardHodges Nope - `void f(int x[7])` is equivalent to `void f(int x[])` which is equivalent to `void f(int* x)`. The length value is ignored and you can pass arrays of arbitrary length. To my original version, you can only pass arrays of length 7! Compare the pointer version (which is possible in C as well) `void f(int (*x)[7])` which is a pointer to an array with length of exactly 7...